# Can user see REDUX store after deployment?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to react and redux and I was wondering if the user can view the REDUX store after I deploy my website. I store some sensitive information such as JWTs on my REDUX store. Using Redux dev tools allows me to see the store of my website and hence, I see the JWT.

But after deployment, will the user be able to do the same if they have REDUX Dev Tools?

Comment: User able to see them all.

Comment: YIKES. So any ideas where will be the best place to store my JWT?

Comment: JWT can see always when you sending API request and it's in the Authorization Header. So no point of hiding it. :)

Comment: Wow they can see the header as well.
So is JWT not sensitive and its fine the user sees it?

Comment: Why are you trying to Safe JWT?

Comment: You are right, I misunderstood JWTs.
It is harmful if someone else knows your JWT, but it makes no difference if the user can see their own JWT.
Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: JWTs are useful because they allow you to authenticate and authorize a user without any additional requests to an authorization server or checking sessions. While anyone can decode a JWT easily, as long as your JWT is signed securely, no one should (in theory) be able to modify it.